# SAN certificate with internal DNS

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'd like to request for a SAN SSL certificate that will handle both publicly accessible and not publicly accessible URLs. Not publicly accessible URLs will be handled by our internal DNS.

The problem is that I'm not sure if it is possible to define subject alternative names that are not publicly accessible in a SAN SSL certificate?

For example:

- foo.com
- www.foo.com
- internal.foo.com
- www.internal.foo.com

foo and www.foo.com will be publicly accessible while internal.foo.com and www.internal.foo.com will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's `internal.foo.com` that would be fine, because the verified asset is still `foo.com`.

If you wanted `www.foo.com` and `foowebserver` (the internal-only routable hostname) then you'd run into issues and need to split the certificate into an internal cert and an external cert (or switch to an internal-DNS-subnet of a registered name scheme).

Comment: Thank you. That is interesting - I actually have multiple top level domains - foo.com and foo.org. Would that affect what the verified asset is as well?

Comment: @TimoLanno if everything you care about ends at a public domain, it’ll cooperate on one cert. You just can’t mix in internal only TLDs, domains, or unqualified host names with public DNS domains.

Comment: So as long as foo.com and foo.org are public I can register internal.foo.com and internal.foo.org as well because the verified assets are public domains. Last clarification - new scenario, if I register a public domain x.foo.com will I be able to register an internal domain internal.foo.com or will the verifiable asset in this case be x.foo.com instead of foo.com?

Comment: @TimoLanno Verification is done at the DNS registration/purchase boundary. If you own foo.com (DNS) you could put anything underneath it. That’s all they verify.

Comment: True, but regarding the SAN certificate. If I buy the certificate only for public domain 'x.foo.com' and internal domain 'internal.foo.com' - will the 'internal.foo.com' work with the certificate?